# Increment a value from 2 different sources in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In my below code value of the memo is incremented in 2 different ways:

1. After the ajax call if (color == white) is true.
2. Also value of the memo can be incremented and decremented by on click eventListener.

The problem I have is that if I increment the value of memo on click (for example to 5), the value of the memo changes to 1 after my ajax call.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

           const minusButtonFw = document.getElementById('memo-minus');
           const plusButtonFw = document.getElementById('memo-plus');
           var memo = document.getElementById('memo');
           memo.val = memo.value;


           minusButtonFw.addEventListener('click', event => {
           const currentValue = Number(memo.value);
           memo.value = currentValue - 1;
           });

           plusButtonFw.addEventListener('click', event => {
           const currentValue = Number(memo.value);
           memo.value = currentValue + 1;
           });

        var ajax_call = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "test.php",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    color = response;
                    console.log(color);
                    if (color == white) {
                        memo.val++;
                        memo.value = memo.val;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Color is not white");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        var interval = 30000;
        setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `success` function increments from `memo.val`. Change that to `memo.value` and you should be OK:

```
function (response) {
  color = response;
  console.log(color);
  if (color == white) {
    memo.value = +memo.value+1;
  } else {
    console.log("Color is not white");
  }
}
```

The unary operator `+` will convert the string value of `memo.value` to a numerical one before `1` will be added to it.

Your code can be shortened significantly:

- As you are using jQuery you might as well also use it to access your DOM elements.
- DRY = **D**ont **R**epeat **Y**ourself: you can assign the click event listener to both buttons in one go.

Below I prepared a little snippet illustrating these points. The lines at the top provide a virtual AJAX testing environment. The function `getColor()` can be used in any AJAX request instead of your external URL `test.php`.

```js
// ====== start of AJAX testing environment =============
// return a random colour as a JSON string (works only with GET):
function getColor() {
  const colors=['black','white','green','blue','red','pink','yellow'],
        idx=Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
  return URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(colors[idx])],{type: "text/json"}));
}
// ====== end of AJAX testing environment ===============

const memo=$('#memo')[0];
$('button[data-inc]').click(function(){memo.value=+memo.value+(+this.dataset.inc)})

setInterval(
  function(){
    $.ajax({type: "GET",
          url: getColor(),
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (color) {
            $('div span').text(color);
            if (color == 'white') { ++memo.value } 
          }
    })
  }, 
  3000
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-inc="-1">-</button>
<input type="text" id="memo" size="1">
<button data-inc="1">+</button>
<div>last returned color: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. Your shortened jQuery code is great and helped me to learn how to code DRY.

Answer (score 2):

Change `memo.val = memo.value;` to `let val = Number(memo.value)`.  Then create two functions:

```js
function valIncrement() {
  val = val + 1;
  memo.value = val;
}

function valDecrement() {
  val = val - 1;
  memo.value = val;
}
```

Your `"click"` handlers are replaced with those two functions, and you replace the following in the AJAX call:

```js
memo.val++;
memo.value = memo.val;
```

That is replaced with just `valIncrement();`

The fact that `memo.value` is supposed to stay in sync with `val` is entirely an implementation detail.  The whole `memo` element is irrelevant to both the AJAX and the handlers: their intent is to increment and decrement a value, and the fact that `memo.value` is staying in sync with that value isn't something they should be aware of: they should just call the function to increment or decrement, and that function should encapsulate the implementation details.

BTW, for bonus points, you can do a closure to increase safety and reduce code duplication:

```js
const [ valIncrement, valDecrement ] = function makeValKnobs() {
  let val = Number(memo.value);
  const f = (amt) => {
    val = val + amt;
    memo.value = val;
  };
  return [ f(1), f(-1) ];
}
```

Now `val` can only be changed by the knobs.  The more important advantage of this approach is that you have precisely one place to change things if you want to change the implementation -- for instance, if you wanted to do a lookup of the `memo` element and extracting its value each time the value changes, so you can safely replace the `memo` element...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting mem.val when page loads, then increase this value each 30s and change memo element with ajax.
So if you click a button it wont change the `memo.val` value, instead it will keep the one from last change.

To avoid this you should check for the most recent value every time you gonna change with your schedule:

```
if (color == white) {
    memo.value = Number(memo.value) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get updated your variable, you could call the ajax method when a click is done to prevent invalid data.